# Backup remote SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, backup

How do I backup data from a remote MS-SQL Server DB to my local computer?

I'm having access to Management Studio 2008.

Comment: AFAIK - you can't, unless you can map a share drive to your machine from the server, but this really goes on serverfault.

Comment: This would be on SO only if he's seeking out the osql command lines to do it.  I sitll answer it though as backing up is a developer task from time to time.

Comment: http://sqldumper.ruizata.com/ solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sqldumper.ruizata.com solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You'd specify the target for the backup file to a UNC path on your local machine.  When you specify to Backup you have to specify a Desination.  That destination can be either a Filename locally pathed to the SQL Server instance (e.g. `E:\Backups\Database.BAK`) or a UNC path such as `\\YOURMACHINENAME\SHAREDFOLDERONYOURMACHINE\FILENAME.BAK`.

Comment: My db is hosted at an ISP. Im not sure my local machine is a accesisble this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to backup the remote database then you can run a query such as

BACKUP DATABASE mydb TO DISK = 'd:\whatever\location\mydb.bak'

Where the 'd:' drive will be local to the SQL Server, otherwise use the format

BACKUP DATABASE mydb TO DISK = '\\mylocalcomputer\share\mydb.bak'

to backup to your machine.

Comment: How do you supply password in this method when the remote PC requires username and password to login

Comment: You'd login using something like SQL Management Studio and run the query i.e. you'd be logging on the the SQL Server, not the PC.